# Ubuntu Server 11.10 interfaces file unreadable

Tags: networking, dhcp, ubuntu-11.10, network-interface

I am configuring ubuntu server 11.10 to go from dhcp to static and whenever I try to restart my networking manager, I get the error: 
command ran:

```
    sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
```

output:

```
*Running /etc/init.d/networking restart is depricated because it may not enable     
again some interfaces
*Reconfiguring network interfaces...
/etc/network/interfaces:10: unknown method
ifdown: couldn't read interfaces file "/etc/network/interfaces"
/etc/network/interfaces:10: unknown method
ifup: couldn't read interfaces file "/etc/network/interfaces"

[fail]
```

I assume the ":10:" means line 10 in the interfaces file but I will post my interfaces file here:

```
#This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).
#The loopback interface

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

#The primary network device
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address   10.x.x.210
        netmask   255.255.255.0
        network   10.x.x.0
        broadcast 10.x.x.255
        gateway   10.x.x.1
```

Is there anything wrong? How do I resolve this error? The line

```
    iface eth0 inet static
```

used to be

```
    iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

Is that the cause? I am trying to configure this to run a dns server, web server, mail server and file server. Can anyone help?

NOTE: I already tried removing the network manager but it will not let me.

Comment: You didn't use 10.x.x.210 in your actual file, correct? You used something like 10.10.10.210, right?

Comment: yes that is correct

Comment: What is the user permissions of that file. The syntax looks fine, so I don't know why it's not reading it. Should be root:root rw-r--r-- (644)

Comment: that is also correct

Comment: Um, just for the heck of it, can you remove the spaces on the "address" line. Did you happen to paste that config from the internet? I'm wondering if you pasted non-display characters or some unicode business you can't see.

Comment: Those are spaces I put in(I am a programmer) to recognize that that info corresponds to the static configuration. That code was not pasted from the internet as I am running ubuntu server with no gui installed. Every configuration was hand coded.

Comment: You may not be able to remove Network Manager, but it's sounds like it's definitely interfering with your networking. What are the contents of /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf?

Comment: That's just it...there is no directory by network manager and it says that the package network-manager and network-manager-gnome are not installed so they were not removed. I think the solution here is to wipe the os out and start fresh.

Comment: Yes, good idea. But when reinstalling do it with a suported version.

Answer (score 1):

If you're configuring it manually then something like this will set the default gateway (network, broadcast and gateway are optional):

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.0.2.7/24
    gateway 192.0.2.254
```

don't use "network" syntax
netmask   255.255.255.0

Comment: This is more of a comment.